# What is “International Quds Day”?

Tags: international

I know that “Al Quds Day (International Quds Day)” is a day that people (often Muslims) protest against Israel and also it is an annual event held on the last Friday of Ramadan, but where did that event come from and how is it related to Islam?

Comment: Although I am almost sure you already know this, it is worth mentioning for readers in other parts of the world that "Al Quds" is the Arabic name for the city of Jerusalem. Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Quds_(disambiguation)

Answer (score 3):

It's an annual anti-Zionist day of protest that was first suggested by Ebrahim Yazdi, the first foreign minister of the Islamic Republic of Iran, to the leader of the Iranian Revolution, Ruhollah Khomeini. The first protest took place in August, 7th 1979. Since then, there have been protests around the world asking for the recognizing of Palestine as a state and the disbandment of the State of Israel.

Understand that this is a political protest that has nothing to do with Islam; anti-zionism (which they support) is a political movement and not a religious one. There are people from other religions supporting the celebration. To put it in perspective [there are extremist Jews](http://www.nkusa.org/activities/Demonstrations/20150710Houston.cfm) against Israel and they march in New York.

Comment: Perhaps instead of saying it has *nothing* to do with Islam you could say that some Muslims believe Islam encourages it but it is primarily an anti-Zionist event.

Comment: Isn't clear when I say that is a **political protest**?

Answer (score -3):

Al Quds Day (International Quds Day)” is a day that people (muslims) protest against Israel and also it is an annual event held on the last Friday of Ramadan

Qods is the first Qiblah of  Muslims. In fact Masjid al-Aqsa which is located in Quds used to be Islam's first qibla as recommended by Quran, 2:42. On the other hand, Quds is a mulsim land under occupation, and likewise these do matter to every sane muslim, right?  Hence we cannot say it is not related to Islam.

As I mentioned, It is the main land of Palestinians (as an Islamic country) that Israel or actually Zionist as an occupier army has occupied it since 1948. This plot of Israel was encountered the resistance of Muslim people of Palestine since those initial years of occupancy.

Islamic Republic of Iran as an Islamic country(in 1979) after the victory of its Islamic revolution), started protesting against this oppressive act of Israel.

**Of course Imam Khomeini as the leader of Iran issued a statement for all Muslims to show their protest against Israel (in Quds Day). Imam Khomeini also mentioned that International Quds Day is not solely Palestine day, it is the day of Islam, it is the day of Islamic rule.**

Initially look at the following  Ayah regarding the attentions of God to the resistance of the oppressed people(Muslims) , so we can pay attention to its comparability with the matter of Palestine resistance.

For instance: (Foselat:30):

> «ان الذين قالو ربنا الله ثم استقاموا تتنزل عليهم الملائكه الا تخافوا و
>   لاتحزنوا و ابشرو بالجنه التي كنتم توعدون»
>
> Indeed, those who have said, "Our Lord is Allah " and then remained on
>   a right course(resistance) - the angels will descend upon them,
>   [saying], "Do not fear and do not grieve but receive good tidings of
>   Paradise, which you were promised.

Accordingly, it could be extracted from the upper ayah that Muslims ought to notice to the subject of Palestine, how come? .. that Palestinians can be compared with the upper ayah as those people who resist…,

But now, look at the following Ayah which could support the question that inquired regarding “how-is-it-related-to-islam” or  actually “why Muslims must pay attention to the Day of Qods.

> . Anfal:72_ ....إِنِ اسْتَنْصَرُوكُمْ فِي الدِّينِ فَعَلَيْكُمُ
>   النَّصْرُ... ؛  In the mentioned  Ayah, it says that if a
>   group(Mo’menin..) asked you to help them because of the protection of
>   their religion and custom, you must help them…  to see the complete
>   Ayah, you can refer to “(tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/8:72)“

so it is extracted from the Ayah that Muslims must help them(Palestinians) as much as possible. Because they asked us to help them, as a result we must help them. At east we can support them(muslims)  by attending in such  a significant day (Quds day) to show our support for the muslim people  of Palestine and likewise to indicate our protest against Israel as an enemy of Islam.

I think there is another verse that emphasizes in helping to Muslims in Palestine, ayah 29 sorah al-fateh:

> "مُحَمَّدٌ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ وَ الَّذينَ مَعَهُ أَشِدَّاءُ عَلَى الْکُفَّارِ رُحَماءُ بَيْنَهُمْ تَراهُمْ رُکَّعاً سُجَّداً يَبْتَغُونَ
>   فَضْلاً مِنَ اللَّهِ وَ رِضْواناً سيماهُمْ في‏ وُجُوهِهِمْ مِنْ أَثَرِ السُّجُودِ ذلِکَ مَثَلُهُمْ فِي التَّوْراةِ وَ مَثَلُهُمْ فِي
>    ...Muhammad is the Messenger of God. Those with him are stern against
>   the disbelievers, yet compassionate amongst themselves. You see them
>   kneeling, prostrating, seeking blessings from God and approval. Their
>   marks are on their faces from the effects of prostration. Such is
>   their description in the Torah, and their description in the Gospel:
>   like a plant that sprouts, becomes strong, grows thick, and rests on
>   its stem, impressing the farmers. Through them He enrages the
>   disbelievers. God has promised those among them who believe and do
>   good deeds forgiveness and a great reward"

If we are Muslims we must accept and obey this order from God.

Also there is another ayah that helps us to understand the necessity of helping to them by participating in the demonstration: ayah 3 sorah Tobah:

> "وَأَذَانٌ مِّنَ اللّهِ وَرَسُولِهِ إِلَى النَّاسِ يَوْمَ الْحَجِّ الأَكْبَرِ أَنَّ اللّهَ بَرِيءٌ مِّنَ
>   الْمُشْرِكِينَ وَرَسُولُهُ فَإِن تُبْتُمْ فَهُوَ خَيْرٌ لَّكُمْ وَإِن تَوَلَّيْتُمْ فَاعْلَمُواْ أَنَّكُمْ غَيْرُ مُعْجِزِي اللّهِ ...And a proclamation from God and His Messenger to the people on the
>   day of the Greater Pilgrimage, that God has disowned the polytheists,
>   and so did His Messenger. If you repent, it will be better for you.
>   But if you turn away, know that you cannot escape God. And announce to
>   those who disbelieve a painful punishment."

Hence, how can you deny its relation with Islam? Since in accordance with the verses above, it could be adapted the concept of the verses with the subject of “Qods day” as an Islamic matter.

---

**Sources:**

[Surah Anfal - Verse 7](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/8:7)

[نگاهي اجمالي به فرهنگ ايثار و مقاومت در قرآن](http://maarefquran.org/index.php/page,viewArticle/LinkID,4162)

[ardanews.com](http://www.fardanews.com/fa/news/215469/%DA%86%DA%AF%D9%88%D9%86%DA%AF%DB%8C-%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%DA%AF%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2%D9%82%D8%AF%D8%B3-%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%DB%8C%D8%AF%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B1%D9%87)

Comment: If you're quoting scripture, then this isn't a politics question as much as a theological one.